# Using hover with several unique elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to make a Tumblr page. The idea is to have several book titles listed on the left side that, when hovered over, display the information for said book on the right side.

[Example](http://s1.postimg.org/uy3lp9fhb/example.png)

There, "Example 2" is being hovered over in the blue box, so its respective information appears in the red box on the right. If I were to hover over "Example 3" from there, the information box for "Example 2" would fade out while the one for "Example 3" would fade in. I hope I'm make some sort of sense here.

Now, I know I could achieve this with pure CSS, but I imagine that would involve creating a custom CSS class for each title in the list. Is there any other way of potentially doing this while avoiding the CSS dance?

Comment: You have to establish a connection between the left items and their corresponding right items no matter what. I'd use 'data-' attributes where '' is the unique identifier connecting left and right sides. Then using JS/Jquery you can just lookup what value 'data-' has on hover and display it only. So you create HTML attributes and toggle the visibility via Jquery. More info about 'data-' http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Pure CSS, one class for all titles - Codepen](http://codepen.io/iamsimon/pen/XbGPdo)

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Example 1</a>
  <div class="show">
    <h1>EXAMPLE 1</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Example 2</a>
  <div class="show">
    <h1>EXAMPLE 2</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Example 3</a>
  <div class="show">
    <h1>EXAMPLE 3</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Example 4</a>
  <div class="show">
    <h1>EXAMPLE 4</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  width: 120px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #2F43B7;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
}

.menu a:hover + .show { /* Select .show that is immediately after a */
  opacity: 1;
}
.show {
  transition: 500ms;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #B72F2F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 130px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.show h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.show h1,
.show p {
  color: #fff;
}

.show hr {
  width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Same effect with **jQuery**:

```
$(".show").css("opacity", 0);
$("a").hover(
function(){
    $(this).next(".show").stop().fadeTo("slow",1);
},
function(){
    $(this).next(".show").stop().fadeTo("slow",0);
});
```